# Highlight duplicates based on first name and last name

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

There are plenty of tutorials on how to conditionally format duplicates in a column, but how can I do this across two key columns without creating a third 'combo' column?

Edit: This formula gets me close:

```
=countifs(A:A,A1, B:B, B1)>1
```

But it only applies the formatting to column A when using A1:B2501 as the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my formula

```
=countifs(A:A,A1, B:B, B1)>1
```

works as long as I create two rules, one for each column